# Convexity of a revolution surface

Tags: differential-geometry, convex-analysis

Let $\Sigma$ be a surface in $\mathbb{H}^2\times\mathbb{R}$ given by the rotation of a curve $\alpha$ around the vertical axis passing through the origin of $\mathbb{H}^2\times\mathbb{R}$. Let $k_\alpha$ be the geodesic curvature of $\alpha$. If $k_{\alpha} >0$, is it true that $\Sigma$ is a convex surface?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{H}^2$?

Comment: The hyperbolic plane